# Trying to create a rotating 'testimonial' ticker with AJAX/JQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I have an XML file containing different testimonial quotes, including the name of the person they're quoted from.

I have a DIV on my page, and I want it to rotate randomly between these XML testimonials - LIVE (without refreshing).

If this can be done easily in JQuery, that would be even better.  I'm just trying to get into AJAX/JQuery, so any guidance would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) will do this easily.

Comment: Oh hell yeah, jQuery Cycle rocks!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response--I've been looking at Jquery Cycle, but i'm having trouble trying to figure out how to combine its functionality with Ajax.  Could you give me a quick example if possible? Thanks!